# How to write dataframe below an existing Excel Sheet with ignoring index column value?

Tags: python, pandas, openpyxl

I am appending a dataframe below an existing excel file. Dataframe is successfully appending below Excel file with the help of following code but index value of dataframe appears as my first column i.e in Column A.

For Example -

1.My Existing excel file is following-

```
   A         B         C                                                                
  10        20        30
  30        40        50
```

2. My dataframe is following df1-

   a = {'A':[10,11,12],'B':[12,13,14],'C':[14,15,16]}
   df1 = pd.DataFrame(a) #Dataframe to be append below existing Excel File

3.After running the code I am getting following Output-

```
   A         B         C     D 
  10        20        30
  30        40        50
   0        10        11    12
   1        12        13    14
   2        14        15    16
```

4.But I want Output as Follows(Desired Output)

```
   A         B         C   
  10        20        30
  30        40        50
  10        11        12    
  12        13        14    
  14        15        16
```

5.Output shown in Step 3 includes index values 0,1 and 2 but I do not want that index value.Instead I want column A must append below column A, Column B below column B and Column C below column C.

In simple words I do not want index values to be appear in my excel file because I am getting wrong Excel File by using index values.

My dataframe data is shifting one column right due to index values present in my dataframe.

My code is

```
#Below is a method to write dataframe value below an existing excel file
    def append_df_to_excel(filename, df, sheet_name='Sheet1', startrow=None        [truncate_sheet][1]=False,
                           **to_excel_kwargs):
        """
        Append a DataFrame [df] to existing Excel file [filename]
        into [sheet_name] Sheet.
        If [filename] doesn't exist, then this function will create it.

        Parameters:
          filename : File path or existing ExcelWriter
                     (Example: '/path/to/file.xlsx')
          df : dataframe to save to workbook
          sheet_name : Name of sheet which will contain DataFrame.
                       (default: 'Sheet1')
          startrow : upper left cell row to dump data frame.
                     Per default (startrow=None) calculate the last row
                     in the existing DF and write to the next row...
          truncate_sheet : truncate (remove and recreate) [sheet_name]
                           before writing DataFrame to Excel file
          to_excel_kwargs : arguments which will be passed to `DataFrame.to_excel()`
                            [can be dictionary]

        Returns: None
        """
        from openpyxl import load_workbook

        import pandas as pd

        # ignore [engine] parameter if it was passed
        if 'engine' in to_excel_kwargs:
            to_excel_kwargs.pop('engine')

        writer = pd.ExcelWriter(filename, engine='openpyxl')

        # Python 2.x: define [FileNotFoundError] exception if it doesn't exist
        try:
            FileNotFoundError
        except NameError:
            FileNotFoundError = IOError


        try:
            # try to open an existing workbook
            writer.book = load_workbook(filename)

            # get the last row in the existing Excel sheet
            # if it was not specified explicitly
            if startrow is None and sheet_name in writer.book.sheetnames:
                startrow = writer.book[sheet_name].max_row

            # truncate sheet
            if truncate_sheet and sheet_name in writer.book.sheetnames:
                # index of [sheet_name] sheet
                idx = writer.book.sheetnames.index(sheet_name)
                # remove [sheet_name]
                writer.book.remove(writer.book.worksheets[idx])
                # create an empty sheet [sheet_name] using old index
                writer.book.create_sheet(sheet_name, idx)

            # copy existing sheets
            writer.sheets = {ws.title:ws for ws in writer.book.worksheets}
        except FileNotFoundError:
            # file does not exist yet, we will create it
            pass

        if startrow is None:
            startrow = 1

        # write out the new sheet
        df.to_excel(writer, sheet_name, startrow=startrow, **to_excel_kwargs)

        # save the workbook
        writer.save()

    import pandas as pd
    a = {'A':[10,11],'B':[12,13],'C':[14,15]}
    df1 = pd.DataFrame(a)          #df1 is datafame which I want to append
    path1 = r"C:\Users\Desktop\ab.xlsx"    #PATH OF EXISTING EXCEL FILE 
    append_df_to_excel(path1, df1, sheet_name='Sheet1')
```

Comment: But I have wriitten clear what I want to ask?

Comment: I want to append dataframe below an existing excel file. But do not want index values to appear in final excel sheet

Comment: I've provided a possible answer, but your question is still quite poorly formatted. Try rewriting it step by step rather than a giant single paragraph for starters. As your code stands I'm not really sure where `a` is being used so rename it to something meaningful, then tell us about how you are using this data `a` and where exactly in the code you are creating it, modifying it, etc. and where you are writing it to the excel sheet. We don't want to have to read your entire code just to figure out where your issue is. You should try to narrow that down for us.

Comment: You should consult the documentation for the `to_excel()` method.

Comment: Can you please tell me what changes I can do in my code in order to achieve desired output?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have found a solution to my asked question.
While calling following function 
`append_df_to_excel(path1, df1, sheet_name='Sheet1', header=None,index = False )`

We must pass header=None and index=False value.
We will get desired output after doing it.

Thank You

Comment: I don't see that as possible, given your current code. You need to pass the `index=false` to the `df.to_excel()` function, not `append_df_to_excel()`, even if you passed it to `append_df_to_excel()` it would never be entered into `df.to_excel()`, and thus you would still get the index values as you have mentioned being your problem.

Comment: It is producing desired output if I pass index = False while calling the function .This parameter is received by **to_excel_kwargs and finally its impact is shown in to_excel function. Finally I am able to write below existing excel and save it.  Try this code and it is working perfectly....

Comment: Then you are calling this `append_df_to_excel()` function outside the code you have posted (e.g. from a live python console). If you want your code to be reproducible, i.e. always appear without these indices in the excel worksheet, you should hardcode, or at least set a default value for the `index` parameter as I have done. You can still pass `index=True` from `append_df_to_excel()` if such a need ever arises.

Comment: Furthermore, your question/issue was focused on the removal of the indices, not any header. According to your example, there was no header in the first place, so setting the `header=None` is irrelevant to your question. Also, the [docs](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.to_excel.html) specify that this should be a boolean (i.e. True or False) not "None" even if you did need to play with this parameter, which again you don't.

Comment: Thanks for your answer.But If we are passing index =False value while method declaration than it is not working. I have tried different ways in the method declaration and definition to provide index=False. But this has not help me .Finally I have provided this value while calling and I have found the solution. Also header = None do not plays any role here.So by removing it also output remains the same

Comment: There are various ways of passing [default args](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/default-arguments-in-python/) in python, but as I have indicated in my answer, you don't need to pass it in the command line, or method declaration, you can simply hardcode it into the line of code where you previously had `df.to_excel(writer, sheet_name, startrow=startrow, **to_excel_kwargs)` should be `df.to_excel(writer, sheet_name, startrow=startrow, index=False, **to_excel_kwargs)`.

Comment: Please avoid asking off-topic questions. If you want to know more around dataframes I recommend you read the [docs](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.html) then return to SO with a specific, well formulated question.

Answer (score 4):

According to the [docs](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.to_excel.html), if you don't want to write row names, you set the index parameters to false.

i.e.

```
df.to_excel(writer, sheet_name, startrow=startrow, **to_excel_kwargs)
```

should be

```
df.to_excel(writer, sheet_name, startrow=startrow, , index=False, **to_excel_kwargs)
```

In the full context of your code (with some housekeeping):

```
import pandas as pd
from openpyxl import load_workbook


def append_df_to_excel(filename, df, sheet_name='Sheet1', startrow=1, truncate_sheet=False, **to_excel_kwargs):

    # ignore [engine] parameter if it was passed
    if 'engine' in to_excel_kwargs:
        to_excel_kwargs.pop('engine')

    writer = pd.ExcelWriter(filename, engine='openpyxl')

    try:
        # try to open an existing workbook
        writer.book = load_workbook(filename)

        # get the last row in the existing Excel sheet
        # if it was not specified explicitly
        if startrow is None and sheet_name in writer.book.sheetnames:
            startrow = writer.book[sheet_name].max_row

        # truncate sheet
        if truncate_sheet and sheet_name in writer.book.sheetnames:
            # index of [sheet_name] sheet
            idx = writer.book.sheetnames.index(sheet_name)
            # remove [sheet_name]
            writer.book.remove(writer.book.worksheets[idx])
            # create an empty sheet [sheet_name] using old index
            writer.book.create_sheet(sheet_name, idx)

        # copy existing sheets
        writer.sheets = {ws.title: ws for ws in writer.book.worksheets}

    except FileNotFoundError:
        # file does not exist yet, we will create it
        pass

    if startrow is None:
        startrow = 1

    # write out the new sheet
    df.to_excel(writer, sheet_name, startrow=startrow, index=False, **to_excel_kwargs)

    # save the workbook
    writer.save()


if __name__ == '__main__':
    a = {'A': [10, 11], 'B': [12, 13], 'C': [14, 15]}
    df1 = pd.DataFrame(a)  # df1 is datafame which I want to append
    path1 = r"C:\Users\Desktop\ab.xlsx"  # PATH OF EXISTING EXCEL FILE
    append_df_to_excel(path1, df1, sheet_name='Sheet1')
```

Comment: It is successfully writing below excel sheet by index=False.But my Excel sheet also contains some sheets which contains pivot table.openpyxl is destroying pivot table.What to do so that my pivot table will not destroy or remove my data from sheet.Is there any other library available to write dataframe below excel file?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59134136/pivot-table-get-destroyed-while-appending-dataframe-below-excel-using-openpyxl

Comment: I am really sorry if you feel bad.But truly speaking I have found the solution by hit and trial only.Really thanking you again and again for your answer and I have marked your answer as correct only.I will delete my own answers also. But Please don't feel bad about it.My purpose not to hurt your feelings.Please forgive me if  i have make any mistake.Really I am thankful to you for your answers