# Slicer in my excel sheet get destroyed while appending dataframe below excel using openpyxl

Tags: python, excel, pandas, openpyxl

I am working with pandas and openpyxl.

### **INPUT FILES**

I have total three input excel files in my program.  With the help of dataframes 
I am processing input excel files and getting a final dataframe after processing.

### **OUTPUT**

After getting final dataframe in my program, I am writing this dataframe below an existing excel file with the help of openpyxl. This excel file contains many worksheets. Some worksheets in this excel file also contains pivot table and slicer. Dataframe is successfully appending below excel file.

**But problem is Slicer of my pivot is getting destroyed while writing dataframe below excel file.**I am getting following warning during execution of my program

```
C:\Users\Desktop\PycharmProjects\MyProject\venv\lib\site-packages\openpyxl\worksheet\_reader.py:292: UserWarning: Slicer List extension is not supported and will be removed
      warn(msg)
```

1. I am using following method to append dataframe below an existing excel sheet with the help of openpyxl-

   ## HELPER FUNCTION TO APPEND DATAFRAME BELOW EXCEL FILE

   def append_df_to_excel(filename, df, sheet_name='Sheet1', startrow=None,
                          truncate_sheet=False,
                          **to_excel_kwargs):
       """
       Append a DataFrame [df] to existing Excel file [filename]
       into [sheet_name] Sheet.
       If [filename] doesn't exist, then this function will create it.

   ```
   Parameters:
     filename : File path or existing ExcelWriter
                (Example: '/path/to/file.xlsx')
     df : dataframe to save to workbook
     sheet_name : Name of sheet which will contain DataFrame.
                  (default: 'Sheet1')
     startrow : upper left cell row to dump data frame.
                Per default (startrow=None) calculate the last row
                in the existing DF and write to the next row...
     truncate_sheet : truncate (remove and recreate) [sheet_name]
                      before writing DataFrame to Excel file
     to_excel_kwargs : arguments which will be passed to `DataFrame.to_excel()`
                       [can be dictionary]

   Returns: None
   """
   from openpyxl import load_workbook

   import pandas as pd

   # ignore [engine] parameter if it was passed
   if 'engine' in to_excel_kwargs:
       to_excel_kwargs.pop('engine')

   writer = pd.ExcelWriter(filename, engine='openpyxl', index=False, data_only = 'True')

   # Python 2.x: define [FileNotFoundError] exception if it doesn't exist
   try:
       FileNotFoundError
   except NameError:
       FileNotFoundError = IOError


   try:
       # try to open an existing workbook
       writer.book = load_workbook(filename)

       # get the last row in the existing Excel sheet
       # if it was not specified explicitly
       if startrow is None and sheet_name in writer.book.sheetnames:
           startrow = writer.book[sheet_name].max_row

       # truncate sheet
       if truncate_sheet and sheet_name in writer.book.sheetnames:
           # index of [sheet_name] sheet
           idx = writer.book.sheetnames.index(sheet_name)
           # remove [sheet_name]
           writer.book.remove(writer.book.worksheets[idx])
           # create an empty sheet [sheet_name] using old index
           writer.book.create_sheet(sheet_name, idx)

       # copy existing sheets
       writer.sheets = {ws.title:ws for ws in writer.book.worksheets}
   except FileNotFoundError:
       # file does not exist yet, we will create it
       pass

   if startrow is None:
       startrow = 1

   # write out the new sheet
   df.to_excel(writer, sheet_name, startrow=startrow, **to_excel_kwargs)

   # save the workbook
   writer.save()
   ```
2. Following line is used to call above helper function

   path_of_existing_excel_file = C:\Users\Desktop\MyExcel.xlsx
       append_df_to_excel(path_of_existing_excel_file, df1, sheet_name='MY-DATA',index = False )

3.I am able to obtain desired output.The only Problem is pivot table in excel is getting destroyed. All the sheets in my excel file which contains pivot table is losing information

Here my output is useless because I lost all the information related to my pivot table.

Hope I am clear. Now I want to ask the way by which my pivot table will not destroy ?
How to do so that sheets which contains pivot table will not be affected by openpyxl?
Or How can write dataframe below excel sheet so that my pivot table will not getting affected?
Any of answers to above question will help me

Comment: I think nobody has answer of my question

Comment: please answer if anybody knows?

Comment: I think there is no way available to avoid this problem.Instead of using openpyxl I think I have to switch to other library

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I have tried many solutions.But There is no solution available with openpyxl.

So this problem can be solved by using xlwings library which is very efficient for data processing